# ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'JetEntityFrameworkProvider' is not registered in the machine or application config file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ms-access, jet-ef-provider

I want to connect my Homepage to an Access-DB. For that I use:

- .NET Framework 4.72 API
- EntityFrameworkProvider.Jet

When I try to run it I receave following message

> System.ArgumentException: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'JetEntityFrameworkProvider' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded.
> Zeile 24:             var result = from Daten_ALT in context.Sammlung
> Zeile 25:                          select Daten_ALT;

This snippet in my homecontroller.cs loks like this:

```
using Sammler_Homepage.Models;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Sammler_Homepage.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult SammlungView()
        {
            Sammlung SammlungSQL = new Sammlung();
            ContextDB context = new ContextDB();

            var result = from Daten_ALT in context.Sammlung
                         select Daten_ALT;

            foreach (Sammlung sammlung in result)
            {
                SammlungSQL.Nummer = sammlung.Nummer;
            }
            ViewBag.Message = SammlungSQL;
            ViewBag.Title = "SammlungView";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

my ContextDB.cs:

```js
using System.Data.Entity;
using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

    namespace Sammler_Homepage.Models
{
    public class ContextDB : DbContext
    {
        public ContextDB() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Sammlung> Sammlung { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My packages.config (reduced to significant part):

```
<packages xmlns="urn:packages">
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.4.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="EntityFrameworkCore.Jet" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" version="3.1.8" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions" version="3.1.8" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers" version="3.1.8" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" version="3.1.8" targetFramework="net472" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" version="3.1.8" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Remotion.Linq" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

And the web.config (reduced to significant part):

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDB.12.0; Data source=C:\...\AKneu.mdb" providerName="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" /-->
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data source=C:\...\AKneu.mdb" providerName="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" />
    <!--add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data source=C:\...\AKneu.mdb" providerName="EntityFrameworkProvider.Jet" /-->
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
  </system.web>    
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <!--provider invariantName="EntityFrameworkCore.Jet" type="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Jet, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore"/-->
      <!--provider invariantName="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" type="JetEntityFrameworkProvider.JetProviderServices, JetEntityFrameworkProvider"/-->
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

As you see, the commets were ways where I tried to solve it. But it didn't help. Do you have any suggestions? Is it because of Linq?

Comment: Why exactly are you mixing up Entity Framework 6 and Entity Framework Core? Which one are you using to try to connect to the database?

Comment: I did it because, only with Entity Framework I could enter sth into base at my ContextDB:  public ContextDB() : base("DefaultConnection"). But that is a good point. Thx. Do you have any idea how I can use my Connecitonstring and Entity Framework Core?

Comment: I messed totally up, with the installation of the EntityFramework Package. So I had to  set up my whole project again

Comment: @mark_da_rat Are you still having issue with this, or were you able to solve it? If not, I'll post you some sample code.